# Double char arrays in Class defintion

Tags: c++

I try do use a multidimensional char array in my inherited class but I my compiler doenst recognize it correctly. The problem does not exists in the main function.

So I tried to do a class Blocks from which I inherit specific shape classes, in order to ultimately make a console Tetris clone. No I want to write , the shape of the objects into a multimensional char array which I then plan to write into my grid which itself will be a multidimensional array. Aside whether that's the best way to do it I just cant seem to access parts of the char array in my classes. It works in my main function though so the way I use char arrays seems to work out in general. So what do I need to change ?

According to the resources i found this is roughly how you would use multidimensional arrays, so I'm stuck.

```
class Blocks 
{
     public:
         int posX = 1;
         int posY;
         int rotation;
};

          class LShape : public Blocks {

 char shape[4][4]; 

 shape[0][0] = '*'; // error say int(0) char cannot contain this sort of elements and cannot initialize entity of type error-type here
     shape[0][1] = '*';
     shape[0][2] = '*';
     shape[1][2] = '*';



       };
```

Comment: `shape[0][0] = '*';` you are not in a function, only in a class. You can do that inside a function, ex. inside a constructor `LShape() { shape[0][0] = '*'; }`. Or you can do initialization `char shape[4][4] = {{'*','*','*', .... },{ ... },{ ... }, ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move that inside some method, (the constructor is a good candidate to init things that a class needs)

```
class Blocks
{
     public:
        int posX = 1;
        int posY;
        int rotation;
};

class LShape : public Blocks
{
public:
    char shape[4][4];
    LShape() : Blocks()
    {
        shape[0][0] = '*';
        shape[0][1] = '*';
        shape[0][2] = '*';
        shape[1][2] = '*';
    }
};
```